# Scheduling a Report In SugarCRM

Tags: report, cron, sugarcrm, schedule, suitecrm

I created a report and scheduled an email to be sent to me daily.
It works when I run it manually but I never received any email.

I looked at the documentation for [SugarCRM 7.6 Pro Scheduling Reports](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.6/Pro/Application_Guide/Reports/#Scheduling_Reports)
but I guess because of the version we use, I don’t have any "Update Schedule" or “Schedule Report" column on my ListView or DetailView.

Does anyone have any idea what steps I can take to make it work? Thanks!